# Python logging is printed twice (1 formatted, 1 not formatted) when calling other python packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, stdout, handler

I have my own logging setup:

```
def init_logger(level, name):
    """
    Create logger and its handlers, and set them to the given level
    """
    from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)

    # set level of logger
    logger.setLevel(level)

    # define custom formats
    formatterFile = logging.Formatter('  * [%(asctime)s]:[%(levelname)s] %(message)s', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    formatterStream = logging.Formatter('  * [%(asctime)s] %(message)s', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    # Create handler writing to 'logfile'.
    logfile_handler = RotatingFileHandler("mylog-file.log", 'w', 10000000, 5)
    logfile_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logfile_handler.setFormatter(formatterFile)
    logger.addHandler(logfile_handler)

    # Add handler for stdout
    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    stream_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)  
    stream_handler.setFormatter(formatterStream)
    logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
```

I'm initializing this logger in my main function, with the name "myname". Then I call it to print some information. In my main script I also call for submodules. Each of these submodules have:

```
#submodule1.py
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("myname.mod1")
def function():
    logger.warning("warning !!")
```

So, in my main script, I have:

```
#myscript.py

import logging
import submodule1

def main():
    init_logger(logging.DEBUG, 'myname')
    logger = logging.getLogger('myname')
    logger.info("some information")
    submodule1.function()
```

With that, I have the expected lines in stdout, with expected format, and I also have a file called "mylog-file.log", containing the same information with its expected format. So, until here, everything works perfectly.

Then, I import another python package (from pip install known_package), and I call one of its functions. This other package is using `import logging` and then `logging.error("message")` (or any other level).
When I call it from my script, the information given by this other tool are not printed (because they don't have a subparser of mine), so this is OK.

BUT, when I recall my logger after this call to `known_package`, I get, in stdout, every log information twice: first with my own format, and then with the default format (the one used in `known_package`).

To sum-up, here is my main script:

```
#myscript.py

import logging
import submodule1
import knownpackage

def main():
    init_logger(logging.DEBUG, 'myname')
    logger = logging.getLogger('myname')
    logger.info("some information")
    submodule1.function()

    knowpackage.say_something("smt") # where there is a line like `logging.info("smt")`

    logger.info("more info")
    logger.warning("more warning")
    submodule1.function()
```

And here is the output:

```
Writes:
* [2018-07-25 14:41:23] some information 
* [2018-07-25 14:41:23] warning!!
* [2018-07-25 14:41:23] more info
INFO:myname:more info
* [2018-07-25 14:41:23] more warning
WARNING:myname:more warning
* [2018-07-25 14:41:23] warning!!
WARNING:myname.mod1: warning !!
```

And, in my `logfile`, I have what I expect:

```
* [2018-07-25 14:41:23]: INFO some information 
* [2018-07-25 14:41:23]: WARNING warning!!
* [2018-07-25 14:41:23]: INFO more info
* [2018-07-25 14:41:23]: WARNING more warning
* [2018-07-25 14:41:23]: WARNING warning!!
```

Anybody has an idea why it duplicates my outputs in stdout with the other format while calling an external package?

Thank you!